# How to display user name based on user id by session

Tags: php, sql, session

I have a problem here which is I want to display the staff name after the staff has entered their staff id. My index.php will display the staff name, but it did not work. The problem here after welcome it display "Resource id #4".

**My table :**

```
  CREATE TABLE `staff` (                    
          `staffid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,         
          `password` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,    
          `staffname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,   
          `staffemail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
          `level` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,            
          PRIMARY KEY (`staffid`)                 
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**index.php :**

```
<?php require_once('Connections/sqlconnection.php');

//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$colname_rsstaff = $_SESSION['staffid'];
if (isset($_GET['staffid'])) {
    $colname_rsstaff = $_GET['staffid'];
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "login.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?     mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
 }
}

mysql_select_db($database_sqlconnection, $sqlconnection);
$query_rsstaff = sprintf("SELECT staffname FROM staff WHERE staff.staffid = %s",     GetSQLValueString($colname_rsstaff, "text"));
$rsstaff = mysql_query($query_rsstaff, $sqlconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsstaff = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsstaff);
$totalRows_rsstaff = mysql_num_rows($rsstaff);
?>
<title>Sistem Pengurusan Stok</title>
<center>
  <form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
    <table width="633" height="431" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td height="124" colspan="2" align="right"><?php include 'header.php'?>
<p><?php echo date("d-m-y")."<br>";?></p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="167" height="262"><?php include 'menu.php'?></td>
        <td width="450" align="center"><p>Welcome
            <?php echo $rsstaff?>
</p>
      <p><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Log out </a></p>
      <p><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>"> </a></p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td height="37" colspan="2"></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
</center>
<? session_destroy()?>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rsstaff);
?>
```

Someone help me please... #Thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `<?php echo $rsstaff?>`, you're printing out the MySQL query resource `$rsstaff`. There's no obvious form for such output to take, so PHP just tells you "it's a resource" instead of anything more meaningful. That's the output you're seeing.

You meant to print out one of the elements of `$row_rsstaff`, presumably the `"staffname"` element.

So:

```
<?php echo $row_rsstaff["staffname"] ?>
```

Comment: @Nurul: Please fill in a customer satisfaction form on your way out.

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE MYSQL_* for it has been deprecated**

This answer is based on what you're trying to do however.

Information found here: [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

When you do `$rsstaff = mysql_query($query_rsstaff, $sqlconnection)`, you are getting a resource back rather than what you expect from doing `SELECT staffname FROM staff WHERE staff.staffid = %s` right to the database.

Try the following:

```
$result = mysql_query($query_rsstaff, $sqlconnection);
$rsstaff = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

then

```
Welcome <?php echo $rsstaff["staffname"]; ?>
```

OR even simpler

```
$rsstaff = mysql_result(mysql_query($query_rsstaff),0);
```

then use your code.

Comment: Okay but the way in which you've changed his variable names is quite confusing.

Comment: but this code is provided by the software.. i've just click the recordset at dreamweaver and it is coded.. whenever i've made a changes it will alert the javascript has an error.. so how?